# Classloader exception while trying to use opencms module plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, classloader, opencms

I'm trying to use opencms module plugin v 0.0.9(http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencmsmoddev/files/) with spring source toolsute which is based on eclipse v. 3.7.2

The opencms module seems to be working, because I can configure it in eclipse preferences.
But when I try to create new module I get following exception:

```
    java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "info.rsdev.eclipse.opencms.module.developer.compatibility.CmsCompatibilityHelper.initCmsSystemInfo(Lorg/opencms/main/CmsSystemInfo;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V" the class loader (instance of info/rsdev/eclipse/opencms/module/developer/loader/OpenCmsClassLoader) of the current class, org/opencms/main/Communicator, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, info/rsdev/eclipse/opencms/module/developer/compatibility/CmsCompatibilityHelper, have different Class objects for the type org/opencms/main/CmsSystemInfo used in the signature
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "info.rsdev.eclipse.opencms.module.developer.compatibility.CmsCompatibilityHelper.initCmsSystemInfo(Lorg/opencms/main/CmsSystemInfo;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V" the class loader (instance of info/rsdev/eclipse/opencms/module/developer/loader/OpenCmsClassLoader) of the current class, org/opencms/main/Communicator, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, info/rsdev/eclipse/opencms/module/developer/compatibility/CmsCompatibilityHelper, have different Class objects for the type org/opencms/main/CmsSystemInfo used in the signature
  loader constraint violation: when resolving method "info.rsdev.eclipse.opencms.module.developer.compatibility.CmsCompatibilityHelper.initCmsSystemInfo(Lorg/opencms/main/CmsSystemInfo;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V" the class loader (instance of info/rsdev/eclipse/opencms/module/developer/loader/OpenCmsClassLoader) of the current class, org/opencms/main/Communicator, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, info/rsdev/eclipse/opencms/module/developer/compatibility/CmsCompatibilityHelper, have different Class objects for the type org/opencms/main/CmsSystemInfo used in the signature
```

It seems that eclipse osgi cannot find appropriate classloader for info/rsdev/eclipse/opencms/module/developer/compatibility/CmsCompatibilityHelper and tries default one. 
Did anybody face with the same problem?

Thanks :)